# Find out which protocol to communicate with a TFT LCD display

Tags: screen, i2c, spi, lcd, nrf51

I have an old smart wristband which has been flashed (no access to the original firmware) and I wanted to learn some embedded development on it.

The wrist band is a MyKronoz zefit 3 hr but seems also to be called L38I. I connect to it using stlink v2.1 with a SWD connection. It has a nRF51822 on it.

My problem is that I can find no datasheet neither for the pcb nor for the screen. The information I have about the screen:

- 1.06 inch TFT LCD 160x64pxl
- it has a rectangular connector of 24pins (12 in each side)

Some data were on the connection ribbon:

- TFT7k0857FPC-AI-E

and some other randomly placed: VGH, GVDD, TE, VPP, GVCL

I found that toggling the pin 0 on the nRF51822 switches the LCD display on and off (maybe it's the backlight of a screen).

I searched a lot to find how to interface with the screen (it's some kind of a challenge) but wasn't able to do anything. don't even know if it's a SPI, I2C, ...etc connection

Do you have any idea about how I can achieve this thing ?

Thanks a lot and sorry for the long text